# What is the grammatical structure of “making such an endeavour unjustified”?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

> The focus on the exterior of a building alone will lead to the increase in construction cost, **making such an endeavour unjustified**.

I want to know about the grammatical structure of this part: *making such an endeavour unjustified*.